# Passing ownProps into component wrapped by Apollo graphql

Tags: typescript, graphql-js, apollo, react-apollo

**Update: Added some clarifications**

I am using the Apollo `graphql` wrapper to wrap a component. I would like to send the `onPaymentLoaded` property from `OwnProps` into the wrapped function. My attempt to do this is shown below. However the code is not going past the TypeScript compiler if I don't include `onPaymentLoaded` as part of the `Result` interface too. This is very confusing. My understanding is that `Result` specifies what comes back from the query - which is just `Payment`. So why is the compiler complaining if I don't add `onPaymentLoaded`?

```
const PAYMENT_QUERY = gql`
    query payment($id: ID!) {
        payment(id: $id) {
            id
            amount
        }
    }
`;

interface Result {
    payment: Payment;
    // ----- If I don't include onPaymentLoaded in the Result,
    //       I get the error shown below. I don't understand why.
    //       onPaymentLoaded is not part of the query result!!!
    onPaymentLoaded: (payment: Payment) => void;
}

type WrappedProps = Result & QueryProps;

interface OwnProps {
    paymentid: string;
    onPaymentLoaded: (payment: Payment) => void;
}

const withPayment = graphql<
    Result,
    OwnProps,
    WrappedProps
>(PAYMENT_QUERY, {
    options: ({ paymentid }) => ({
        variables: { id: paymentid }
    }),
    props: ({ data, ownProps }) => ({ ...data, ownProps })
});

export const PaymentContainer = withPayment(
    // ----- Error if interface Result above does not include onPaymentLoaded:
    //       Type 'Response & QueryProps<OperationVariables> &
    //       { children?: ReactNode; }' has no property 'onPaymentLoaded'
    //       and no string index signature."
    ({ loading, error, payment, onPaymentLoaded }) => {
        return (
            <PaymentView
                loading={loading}
                error={error}
                payment={payment}
                onPaymentLoaded={onPaymentLoaded}
            />
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding first error, shrthand syntax for object properties doen't allow dots in notation. Also, most likely, you dont need to transform props at all, because your onPaymentLoaded will be passed down anyway.

Secondly,

`graphql< TResult = {}, TProps = {}, TChildProps = ChildProps<TProps & TResult>`

which means you only need to pass TResult as youve done and TProps which should equal your InputProps and leave out the third generic

Also I would recommend to use recompose's compose func, as graphql enhancer probably wont be the only one.

Hope this example if mine will help:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import graphql from 'react-apollo/graphql';
import { QueryProps } from 'react-apollo';

import { MenuDishQuery } from '@admin/graphql/types.gen';
import { MenuDish as MenuDishPres } from '@admin/components';
import { dataLoadingOrError } from '@common/utils';

const DATA_QUERY = require('./data.gql');

type OwnProps = {
  recipeId: string;
}

type Data = { data: MenuDishQuery.Query & QueryProps }

type WrappedProps = OwnProps & Data;


export const MenuDish = compose<WrappedProps, OwnProps>(

  graphql<MenuDishQuery.Query, WrappedProps>(DATA_QUERY, {
    options: props => ({
      variables: {
        recipeId: props.recipeId
      }
    })
  }),

  dataLoadingOrError()


)(props => {

  const { data } = props;
  const { recipe } = data;

  return <MenuDishPres
    dish={{ recipe }}
  />


});
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your detailed response. I have arrived at a similar conclusion since I posted my question - so I am marking your answer as correct. However I do have one unanswered question. Please see my update to the question and the code. It would be great if you could provide your thoughts. P.S. (1) I am not jumping to compose yet, because I am first trying to understand the basic usage of the `graphql` HOC. (2) You may be correct that I may not need transformation of props at all - haven't tried this yet.

Comment: Hi @Naresh , I've uploaded a gist where I refactored your code to the way how I usually do it. Hope it will help!
https://gist.github.com/rasdaniil/67e12967a42571519bfbc59a8e870739

Comment: That's very helpful, @Daniel. Thanks again for taking the time to do this.